# how to set alias for the folder in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to set the alias for the "abc-abc" folder as "abc" in Linux.Can you help me?

EX:  /raj/abc-abc/xyz/data

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean a symbolic link?  I think so .. but the "system-calls" tag you've put there is throwing me off a bit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

```
ln -s /raj/abc-abc /raj/abc
cd /raj/abc
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to make a "link" from `abc` to `abc-abc`.

```
ln -s /raj/abc-abc /raj/abc
```

Generally you want to create "symbolic links" or "symlinks", which is done using the `-s` flag.